# MarkerOptions .tag not available

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a DefaultClusterRenderer class and my own ClusterItem, which I am using as marker on the map. I am setting the title and snippet with MarkerOptions, so I can grap them on my onInfoWindowClick event. I wanna start a new Activity, depends on which infoWindow the user clicked, but I cant add a tag to MarkerOptions, so I cant get the tag in my onInfoWindowClick method via the Marker parameter.

I am looking for a good solution to add an id to each ClusterItem and get the id via Marker in onInfoWindowClick.

```
public class OwnClusterRendering extends DefaultClusterRenderer<GeoPoint>  {

    private GoogleMap map;

    public OwnClusterRendering(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<GeoPoint> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
        this.map = map;
    }

    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(GeoPoint geoPoint, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        markerOptions.icon(geoPoint.getIcon());
        markerOptions.snippet(geoPoint.getSnippet());
        markerOptions.title(geoPoint.getTitle());
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(geoPoint, markerOptions);
    }
}
```

MyCustomWindowAdapter:

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    Log.d("test", marker.getTitle());
    Log.d("test", marker.getSnippet());
    Log.d("test", marker.getId());
    Log.d("test", String.valueOf(marker.getTag()));

   // Intent intent = new Intent(context, StoneInfoSliderActivity.class);
   // context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved it with the following method from DefaultClusterRenderer<>

```
@Override
protected void onClusterItemRendered(GeoPoint geoPoint, Marker marker) {
    marker.setTag(geoPoint.getId());
    super.onClusterItemRendered(geoPoint, marker);
}
```